# JDBC Connect progress 9.1D DB using java on windows

Tags: java, database, jdbc, progress-db

I'm trying to connect(`JDBC`) progress 9.1D database using java on windows pc. Still i have no idea about progress DB connection.

i want to know these

1. Which libraries(.jar) do i need to use?
2. How to connect progress 9.1D using java?

I tried `jdbc.jar`,`progress.jar` libraries, `com.progress.sql.jdbc.JdbcProgressDriver` driver and `jdbc:jdbcprogress:T:host:port:db`

but it's failed! Can anyone drag me into correct line?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/19308

Comment: this program getting error! i used jdbc.jar, progress.jar, message.jar. And progress 9.1d db is not my pc, it's on another pc on my network. plese help me to solve this error

    `No suitable driver found for jdbc:jdbcprogress:T:host:port:db
    java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for   jdbc:jdbcprogress:T:host:port:db
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
 at progressdb.NewClass.main(NewClass.java:26)`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but it isn't answered yet.

You need jdbc.jar (on your class path). Also this is not a "pure java" driver and it relies on JdbcProgress.dll and procli92.dll. These two dlls must be available to jdbc.jar at run time, so you should change your PATH environment variable to include the directory containg these dll's (or drop them into C:\Windows which is already on the path).

Using Squirrel SQL (java SQL client), with the following connection string
jdbc:jdbcprogress:T:192.168.2.230:5612:yourDBname 
I was able to connect to a progress DB listening on 192.168.2.230 port 5612.

Note that the progress installation HAS to have a SQL database broker started (default start is 4GL only, not SQL) for any connection to be made.
This can be done on the progress machine with 
$propath/bin/proserve fullPathNameToDBFile -S uniqueListenPort(5612 in my example above) -m3 -Mpb 5 -Ma 5 -Mi 5 -ServerType SQL
AFTER you have started the normal 4GL data broker.